# Jest/node.js: customise console.log output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I have some `AWS` lambdas written in `typescript` that I'm unit testing with `jest`.

The tests are working fine, but the output from `console.log` lines in the code verbose and difficult to scan.

When a test is run, in my console I see something like:

```
  console.log src/main/ts/worker/receivemail/ReceiveMailWorker.ts:24
    ctor()

  console.log src/main/ts/shared/LambdaUtil.ts:12
    initConfig() doing initialisation

  ...
```

Jest (or something else?) is writing three lines of output for every call to `console.log()`.

When I'd rather see something like:

```
ctor()
initConfig() doing initialisation
...
```

I wouldn't mind seeing some timestamps too.

Is there any way to configure / control this logging output?

Things to note:

- I don't want to change the actual code - I especially don't want to add a fully blown logging library or anything like that.
- I still want to see the console logging (i.e. `--silent` is definitely not what I want).
- I'm not trying to *test* the console logging, I just want to make it easier to read.
- I tried `--verbose=false` - but it didn't seem to make any difference.